# Is it possible to use useStorage() hook in shopify's webpixel api

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-template, shopify-api-node

I am new to shopify and struggling to implement useStorage() as there does not seem to be much of an example on the net. It is a react hook but I could not find where to include it from.

I see several related APIs listed at the bottom of the [documentation](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/checkout-ui-extensions/2023-07/react-hooks/storage/usestorage)

The below does not help either and it feels strange to include it from checkout (not sure if this is true to begin with) as I am implementing webpixels. Hence, is it possible to do this for webpixel api? If not how can I access to localstorage or sessionstorage?

```
import { useStorage } from '@shopify/ui-extensions-react/checkout';
```

Thanks,

Doug